# How to share manifests across environments in Puppet-provisioned Vagrant project

Tags: vagrant, manifest, puppet, environment

Consider the following Puppet-provisioned Vagrant project directory structure:

```
environments/
  dev/
    manifests/
      site.pp   <- Some standard Puppet stuff in here.
  prod/
    manifests/
      site.pp   <- Very similar to dev/manifests/site.pp, but with some prod differences
manifests/
  default.pp    <- Empty, but a place I'd like to keep common parts of the site.pp files
modules/
Vagrantfile     <- See below.
Puppetfile
```

and the following (simplified) Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

envs = ["local", "dev"]

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "puppetlabs/centos-7.0-64-puppet"

  envs.each do |env|
    config.vm.define env do |node|
      node.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
        puppet.environment_path = "environments"
        puppet.module_path = "modules"
        puppet.environment = env
      end
    end
  end
end
```

What options are available to me if I'd like to factor out the common parts of the two `site.pp` files into a single file?

---

I have tried the following strategies to no avail:

**1 - One Manifest Per Environment Which "Inherits" From a Single Project-Wide Manifest**

After some reading I'm not even sure this is possible.  There used to be the `import` command which I feel like could have been what I was looking for, but that has been deprecated in newer versions of Puppet.

**2 - A Single Project-Wide Manifest and One Hiera File Per Environment**

I consider this the least-attractive of the two options since it means the only way to distinguish between environments is via data, and some things are just better expressed with differences in manifests.

However I can't even get this to work.  Given the following `environment.conf` files in the `dev/` and `prod/` folders:

```
manifest = ../../manifests/default.pp
```

gives me an error about not being able to find the `default.pp` file.

---

Basically I need to a way to stop duplication between environments.  My project is actually more complicated than that above, given that the manifests are getting rather large and unwieldy, and I have more than two environments.  I also feel like the fact I'm using Vagrant here (which has it's own ways of passing options to Puppet) is complicating things further.

Any help at all would be appreciated here.

Comment: I'd also like to be able to share a manifest across multiple environments. I'm trying to have a "base" pack that applies to all environments, and then specialise within each environment's manifests folder. As ever, when I can't believe something so obvious isn't easy, it probably means I'm taking the wrong approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here's what I went with.  Not what I originally wanted but I'm still new to Puppet and not even convinced what I wanted is possible anyway.

I settled on using hiera data to distinguish between environments, and am now using a single manifest (`default.pp`).  The two `site.pp` files are completely empty, and are only there as placeholders so Git keeps the `dev` and `prod` folders.  Rather than have `environment.conf` files pointing towards the manifest, I simply added the following to the `Vagrantfile`:

```
puppet.manifest_file = "default.pp"
```

I also have started putting things into their own modules, rather than having a huge monolithic manifest.

Comment: This actually results in "all in one file", or not? Did you by now find a better solution for the problem, or are you still going with this hack?

Comment: @Martin This doesn't help you out but actually in the end my solution was to drop Puppet entirely and to go with Docker instead.  I haven't touched Puppet in nearly a year and am having trouble remembering the details of my Puppet-related work.  FWIW, the project I was working on is at https://github.com/icatproject-contrib/puppet-icat.  It seems that I was using Beaker to manage the Vagrant stuff indirectly, and I do remember my code was heavily inspired by fatmcgav's GlassFish module, a dependency of the project also up on GitHub.

Comment: Further, I remember the per-server "configuration" side of things was managed by our admins, who have adopted the "Roles and Profiles" approach advocated by Gary Larriza, who has a blog here: http://garylarizza.com/blog/archives/.  The admins were importing my "puppet-icat" module and injecting configuration into it. Sorry I couldn't be of more help, hopefully there is enough information there to set you in the right direction.